# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in Reactjs Add to cart functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, undefined, cart

I have an AddtoCart functionality which is throwing undefined error on click to add products into cart.

**The error is in this function, index.js**

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
if (nextState.cartPopup && nextProps.reducerKeyProductCartPage !== this.props.reducerKeyProductCartPage && nextProps.reducerKeyProductCartPage) {
            if (nextProps.reducerKeyProductCartPage.status && nextProps.reducerKeyProductCartPage.status[0].toLowerCase().includes("error")) {
                this.notify(nextProps.reducerKeyProductCartPage.message[0]);
            }
            else {
                this.notify(nextProps.reducerKeyProductCartPage.message[0], "success");
            }
            this.setState({ cartPopup: false });
        }
}
```

**Below is the add to cart function:**

```
addToCart = (data) => {
        this.setState({ cartPopup: true, deleteCart: false });
        let customerId = cookie.load("customerId") ? cookie.load("customerId") : 0;
        let getUrl = '';
        let stateProductData = {}
        if (customerId) {
            getUrl = constant.BaseUrl + this.state.languageValue + "-" + this.state.storeValue + "/rest/V1/customer/addtocart";
            stateProductData = { "customer_id": customerId, "lang": this.state.languageValue + "_" + this.state.storeValue, "product_id": data, "quantity": 1 }
        }
        else {
            getUrl = constant.BaseUrl + this.state.languageValue + "-" + this.state.storeValue + "/rest/V1/customer/guestaddtocart";
            stateProductData = { "quote_id": cookie.load("cartValue"), "lang": this.state.languageValue + "_" + this.state.storeValue, "product_id": data, "quantity": 1 }

        }
        this.props.commonGateway({
            reqData: stateProductData,
            url: getUrl, method: 'POST',
            resource: "cartProduct", reducerKey: "reducerKeyProductCartPage"
        });
        this.props.commonGatewayRequestDone({ reducerKey: "reducerKeyProductCartStatus" });
    }
```

**Below is the render method which is having add to cart button in other component:**

```
return (
<div>
<MainContainer block={idx + 2} fetchData={this.fetchData} data={this.props["reducerKeyFetchLandingPage" + (idx + 2)] ? this.props["reducerKeyFetchLandingPage" + (idx + 2)] : ""} addToCart={this.addToCart} addToWishList={this.addToWishList} rtl={this.state.languageValue} />
</div>
);
```

screenshot of error [image]

Comment: first console this `nextProps.reducerKeyProductCartPage` are you getting the message or not

Comment: Do a console.log(nextProps.reducerKeyProductCartPage) and share, clearly the message property is undefined and an array index of 0 does not exist.

Comment: @NarendraChouhan : Console log shows `undefined ` as well, How to fix this ?

Comment: @H.Husain then you should check whether you are getting all the values in nextProps or not  componentWillUpdate; pls console and check

Comment: @NarendraChouhan : I did `console.log` without `.message` and it shows that no data is being added on post request. this is returned in console `{items: Array(0), total_items_in_cart: 0}` what could be the reason ? Any problem in code or at the API endpoint ?

Comment: api issue pls check it

Comment: @NarendraChouhan : So my questions is why it did not go to Error condition and displayed the error message ? `if (nextProps.reducerKeyProductWishlistPage.status && nextProps.reducerKeyProductWishlistPage.status[0].toLowerCase().includes("error")) {
                this.notify(nextProps.reducerKeyProductWishlistPage.message[0]);
            }`

Comment: your api would have been sending empty response, that why i would have not been going in the error message